# Separar palavras usando split

Tags: java

Queria imprimir só palavras que tenham `:` na frente

Exemplo: `Coisa1:kit1:Coisa2:kit2;grupo;grupo2;grupo3` apareceria somente: `Coisa1 kit1 Coisa2 kit2`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Coisa1:kit1:Coisa2:kit2;grupo;grupo2;grupo3";
    String[] splitado1 = s.split(":");
    for (int i = 2; i < splitado1.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(splitado1[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse exemplo simples que você deu, bastaria fazer um split antes do ";" e pegar o primeiro elemento, assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Coisa1:kit1:Coisa2:kit2;grupo;grupo2;grupo3";
    String[] splitado1 = str.split(";")[0].split(":");
    for (String s: splitado1) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

**Saída:**

> ```
> Coisa1
> kit1
> Coisa2
> kit2
> ```

Porém, sugiro dar mais exemplos de entrada para que possamos entender o quê exatamente você precisa parsear, até para incluir validações em caso de erros.

Comment: Funcionou rafael, como faço agora pra pegar apenas os "grupos" ?

Comment: Mais uma vez usando o exemplo dado, o mais simples é trocar por: String[] splitado1 = str.substring(str.indexOf(";")+1).split(";");   Porém, como disse, se você tiver outros exemplos é capaz de quebrar. Tem que entender o que está sendo feito para criar uma solução mais robusta.

Comment: Valeu rafa, funcionou.